# XmlTextWriter cannot be found after using system.xml

Tags: .net, xml, xmltextwriter

I have enabled using.System.XML but it cannot find the XmlTextWriter.
I saw that this is the using that i need in order to get it.
Please help!
I am using VS Pro 2013

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `XmlTextWriter` you'll also need to add a reference to the **System.Xml** assembly.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ma kore haim? I mentioned that i used the system.xml.
However, after manually writing it with case sensitive letters it recognized it. Thanks

Comment: Hakol Tov. You only mentioned adding `using System.Xml` **namespace**, did you also add a reference to the **assembly**?

Comment: yes i did but isn't it the same?
it doesnt matter it works now. :)